# Threaded Messaging System

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Am building a threaded messaging system, i have the following tables

```
conversations_inbox
id
R_id
S_id
message
read
post_time
conv_id

conversation_outbox 
id
R_id
S_id
message
read
post_time
conv_id

conversation_meta
id
sender_id
reciever_id
datetime
```

The `conversations_inbox` and `conversation_outbox` have a foreign key `conv_id` which tracks a messaging thread between two users
I hit a snag when i was working on the messaging inbox, am trying to group the messages in the inbox by the `sender_id(S_id)` instead of show each new message a user receives as new row.So all the messages to user in the box is grouped under the user that sent it and the newest message from that user is displayed.

i have tried

```
function get_user_conversations($user_id) {
       //Load Models
       $this->load->model('conversation_model');
       //Load helper
       $this->load->helper('date');
       //database query
       $q = $this->db->select('R_id,message,post_time,read,conv_id')
                     ->from('conversations_inbox')
                     ->where('R_id',$user_id)
                     ->group_by('S_id')
                     ->order_by('post_time','desc')
                     ->get();
        $conversations = $q->result();
        return $conversations;
   }
```

But it only returns one row of data for each Sender id
Please i'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

First I'll state that before now I've never heard of codeigniter...

I'm thinking its because you call `->order_by('post_time','desc')` after `group_by`, try switching those two around, order them while they are not grouped is the thought...

[Just found this forum with a similar problem](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160777/)